# Finding Missing points from unorganised point cloud using PCL

Tags: point-clouds, printer-control-language

I wish to get the region (coordinates) of region that has no point data in the point cloud. I am using PCL library and inpput is .pcd file.

Look at the visulaization. [Viewed in pcl viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q67Hn.jpg)

I need to extract only those black region (infact seems to be black as background was black)

Some suggested to find NaN values. Bit the .pcd file does not seems to have such entries!

Look at the data in the pcd file. [View of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXk0Y.jpg)

How do I do it?

Help.